# How do I run commands after build.dart builds?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

`build.dart` is run by Dart Editor whenever a file changes. Many developers use build.dart to compile their Web UI apps. How can I run other commands after Web UI compiler finishes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `build()` function returns a `Future`. You can register a callback to run after build() runs.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var args = new List.from(new Options().arguments);
  args.addAll(['--', '--no-rewrite-urls']);

  Future dwc = build(args, ['web/clock_page.html']);

  dwc
    .then((_) => Process.run('cp', ['packages/browser/dart.js', 'web/out/dart.js']))
    .then((_) => Process.run('cp', ['App.css', 'out']));
}
```

Learn more:

- [Future](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html)
- [Process](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/Process.html)

Comment: @Seth How about some more infos about build.dart (a blog post?)? Sounds interesting...